# displacement is leaning to one side, but material preview is fine

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, displacement

I have made my spaceship an UV-unwrapped everything, so that it looks exactly how I want it. Everything works well in material preview as you can see:

[image]

The problem I am facing is that when I go into cycles rendered view to get my material displaced, which is the main purpose of it, it looks different, and weird. The displacement is heavily leaning towards one side (the left in this picture).

[image]
here is a better view of the leaning from the side:

[image]

Why is this happening and how I could fix it?

Comment: Maybe change the midlevel of the displacement?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett that did not work, but I but you helped me find the solution, which was to change the space from object space to world space. I have no idea why it worked, but it did.

Comment: @DraugR you should write an answer in the answer section rather than as an edit to your question. This site works differently than others, adding “solved” to the title isn’t the way users find answers.

Comment: Hi. Please don't add "*Solved*" to your question or title. Instead we encourage you to post an answer below with a short description of the solution and what steps you took to reach it. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: What you did for fix it? I dont know what is a object space and world space.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the space from object space to world space, I don't know why it worked but it did.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and procedure. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the workflow and how it works, feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be converted to a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)